# Group by using COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions

I want to create a new column with the counts of repeated elements based on other 3 columns. When I try on the group by to add, i_count I get the following error SQL state: 42P20.

```
SELECT
  cst,
  st,
  co,
  COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY cst,st,co ) AS count
  --mean of loss by co
FROM s.tb_st , s.tb_cst , s.tb_co , erp.tb_i
WHERE st != 'te'
GROUP  BY cst,st ,co, count
ORDER BY cst , st, co;
```

input

```
  cst          | st              |  co         

  sal          | pa              |  ctr          
  sal          | pa              |  ctr          
  sal          | pa              |  est          
  sal          | re              |  ctr         
  sal          | re              |  ctr          
  sal          | re              |  ust          
  cus          | pa              |  ctr          
  cus          | re              |  ctr          
  cus          | re              |  ctr          
  cus          | re              |  ctr
```

my wrong output

```
  cst          | st              |  co           |count 

  sal          | pa              |  ctr          | 55    
  sal          | pa              |  est          | 55    
  sal          | re              |  ctr          | 55    
  sal          | re              |  ust          | 55   
  cus          | pa              |  ctr          | 55    
  cus          | re              |  ctr          | 55
```

expected output

```
  cst          | st              |  co           |count 

  sal          | pa              |  ctr          | 2    
  sal          | pa              |  est          | 1    
  sal          | re              |  ctr          | 2   
  sal          | re              |  ust          | 1    
  cus          | pa              |  ctr          | 1    
  cus          | re              |  ctr          | 3
```

Comment: The window function operates on the grouped result. So you can't refer to `count` because that isn't yet calculated.  Try removing `count` from the GROUP BY terms.  It's best to provide the CREATE TABLE statements as part of the question.  That might be necessary to answer fully.

Comment: It's also unclear why you're generating a cross join / cartesian product between those 4 tables.  What are those tables and what is the meaning of all this?  Lots of missing detail.

Comment: There are no actual tables provided and the `loss` column is completely undefined.  If you can add that detail (about `loss`) to the question (at least add `loss` to the input data), I'll update the answer to address that detail.

Comment: The data in your question does not support the result you obtained.  Please provide a complete test case with data that produces the result you are showing.  Reduce the test case to the minimal amount necessary to show the behavior, if you wish.  **Note: I showed the SQL which produces the correct/expected result (in my answer).**  I don't know why you're trying to use a window function for that.

Answer (score 0):

Your use of a window function appears to be misplaced.  The expected output in the question has a column (`lossmeanbyco`) which is completely undefined, so let's just remove that from the question.  No detail was specified.

The original tables are undefined, so let's just take your question input (which isn't input at all) and make a new table called "test" containing that data.

[Test case](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=d3c472241c39b732b4eb45894b7fdde8)

```sql
CREATE TABLE test ( cst  varchar(5), st  varchar(5),  co  varchar(5) );

INSERT INTO test VALUES
  ('sal'          , 'pa'              ,  'ctr')
, ('sal'          , 'pa'              ,  'ctr')
, ('sal'          , 'pa'              ,  'est')
, ('sal'          , 're'              ,  'ctr')
, ('sal'          , 're'              ,  'ctr')
, ('sal'          , 're'              ,  'ust')
, ('cus'          , 'pa'              ,  'ctr')
, ('cus'          , 're'              ,  'ctr')
, ('cus'          , 're'              ,  'ctr')
, ('cus'          , 're'              ,  'ctr')
;
```

The result column `count` is easily generated with simple aggregation:

```sql
SELECT cst
     , st
     , co
     , COUNT(*) AS count
  --mean of loss by co
  FROM test
 WHERE st != 'te'
 GROUP  BY cst,st ,co  -- , count
 ORDER BY cst , st, co
;
```

The result:

| cst | st | co | count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| cus | pa | ctr | 1 |
| cus | re | ctr | 3 |
| sal | pa | ctr | 2 |
| sal | pa | est | 1 |
| sal | re | ctr | 2 |
| sal | re | ust | 1 |

This seems to be about all that can be done with the limited detail provided.

Comment: The output I receive is wrong, I recieve the count column with the same values for all the rows

Comment: @krlm It's correct.  The window function acts on the final grouped result.  If that's the question you want to ask, just ask that question.  Forget the rest.  Show the exact input data, the exact query you attempted, **the exact result you obtained and explain the exact result you wished to generate**.